# Javascript - Cannot instantiate firebase-firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to follow the google [Getting Started With Cloud Firestore on the Web - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Vf1D-rUMwE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX)

For some reason I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-firestore - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.

But I believe I have everything done as it should be. What is wrong with this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1 id="hotDogOutput">Hot dog status:</h1>
<input type="textfield" id="latestHotDogStatus">
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const firestore = firebase.firestore();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);

const docRef = firestore.doc("samples/sandwichData");

const outputHeader = document.querySelector("#hotDogOutput");
const inputTextField = document.querySelector("#latestHotDogStatus");
const saveButton = document.querySelector("#saveButton");

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const textToSave = inputTextField.value;
    console.log("I am going to save " + textToSave + " to Firestore");
    docRef.set({
       hotDogStatus: textToSave
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Status Saved!");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", error)
    });

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either import the entire `firebase.js` or just `firebase-app.js` followed by `firebase-firestore.js`. What's happening here is that the `firebase-firestore.js` expects `firebase-app.js` (The core Firebase client) and not the entire library.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Helpful Guide:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 5):

If you are using real time database, then add only these two script srcs:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
```